# Transforming canvas point to canvas context point

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas built with Fabric js. I need to draw rectangles of 1x1 pixels on mouse down event at the clicked coordinate. When a click is made in the canvas the point must be converted if the canvas has been transformed before. For doing that i am using the following approach:

```
const point = new fabric.Point(offsetX, offsetY);
const invertedMatrix = fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform)
const transformedPoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, invertedMatrix);
```

After converting the point i just add the rectangle:

```
const p = new fabric.Rect({
 left: transformedPoint.x,
 top: transformedPoint.y,
 fill: 'red',
 width: 1,
 height: 1,
});
this.add(p);
```

The problem is that the transformed point is not 100% accurate and the rectangle is always drawn X pixels away from the original point.

I made a snippet to explain this behaviour. The context is initially transformed with a zoom of 60:

```js
    fabric.Object.prototype.selectable = false;
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    canvas.setWidth(screenWidth);
    canvas.setHeight(screenHeight);
    canvas.setZoom(60);
    canvas.on('mouse:down', (opt) => {
      const evt = opt.e;
      canvas.selection = false;
      canvas.isDragging = true;
      const point = new fabric.Point(opt.e.offsetX, opt.e.offsetY);
      const iM = fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform);
      const transformedPoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, iM);
      const p = new fabric.Rect({
       left: transformedPoint.x,
       top: transformedPoint.y,
       fill: 'red',
       width: 1,
       height: 1,
      });
      canvas.add(p);
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

What am i missing here? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. I thought the problem was transforming the point! But actually it was something as silly as that fabric was drawing an invisible border.
All I had to do was set **Object.strokeWidth = 0**